# java Get the list or name of all attributes in a XML element

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

i have an xml element

```
   <base baseAtt1="aaa" baseAtt2="tt">
        <innerElement att1="one" att2="two" att3="bazinga"/>
   </base>
```

and i would like to get the list of attributes.
for **both** the base element and the inner element.

i **dont know** the name of the innerElement
 it can have many different names.

```
 NodeList baseElmntLst_gold  = goldAnalysis.getElementsByTagName("base");
 Element baseElmnt_gold = (Element) baseElmntLst_gold.item(0);
```

the goal is to get a kind of dictionary as output,

for example for the xml above the output will be a dictionary with those valuse.

```
baseAtt1 = "aaa"
baseAtt2 = "tt"
att1 = "one"
att2 = "two"
att3 = "bazinga"
```

i am using jre 1.5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is plain DOM based solution (however there is nothing wrong to combine XPath with DOM in Java):

```
NodeList baseElmntLst_gold  = goldAnalysis.getElementsByTagName("base");
Element baseElmnt_gold = (Element) baseElmntLst_gold.item(0);

NamedNodeMap baseElmnt_gold_attr = baseElmnt_gold.getAttributes();
for (int i = 0; i < baseElmnt_gold_attr.getLength(); ++i)
{
    Node attr = baseElmnt_gold_attr.item(i);
    System.out.println(attr.getNodeName() + " = \"" + attr.getNodeValue() + "\"");
}

NodeList innerElmntLst_gold = baseElmnt_gold.getChildNodes();
Element innerElement_gold = null;
for (int i = 0; i < innerElmntLst_gold.getLength(); ++i)
{
    if (innerElmntLst_gold.item(i) instanceof Element)
    {
        innerElement_gold = (Element) innerElmntLst_gold.item(i);
        break; // just get first child
    }
}

NamedNodeMap innerElmnt_gold_attr = innerElement_gold.getAttributes();
for (int i = 0; i < innerElmnt_gold_attr.getLength(); ++i)
{
    Node attr = innerElmnt_gold_attr.item(i);
    System.out.println(attr.getNodeName() + " = \"" + attr.getNodeValue() + "\"");
}
```

Result:

```
baseAtt1 = "aaa"
baseAtt2 = "tt"
att1 = "one"
att2 = "two"
att3 = "bazinga"
```

Comment: why just get first child in second loop, i always gare first row data and unable to get second and third continue?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this XPath to retrieve all attributes of 1st `element` node:

```
base/element[1]/@*
```

To get all attributes of all nodes in your XML yo can use this expression:

```
//@*
```

Comment: @yossi, XPath is cross-platform technology. Java supports XPath, but I don't know syntax and Java's classes to evaluate this expression.

Comment: @yossi, May be this link is helpful: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html

Answer (score 2):

If you use XPath you will have less code, but for a dom base solution I have a suggestion here:

```
public void printElementsAndAttributes() throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    org.w3c.dom.Document doc = db.parse(new File("test.xml"));
    NodeList base = doc.getElementsByTagName("base");
    Node basenode = base.item(0);
    System.out.println(basenode.getNodeName() + getAttributesAsString(basenode.getAttributes()));
    NodeList children = basenode.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
        Node item = children.item(i);
        if (item.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            System.out.println(item.getNodeName() + getAttributesAsString(item.getAttributes()));

        }
    }


}

private String getAttributesAsString(NamedNodeMap attributes) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < attributes.getLength(); j++) {
        sb.append("\t- ").append(attributes.item(j).getNodeName()).append(": ").append(attributes.item(j).getNodeValue()).append("\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this method..

```
 public static void listAllAttributes(Element element) {

             System.out.println("List attributes for node: " + element.getNodeName());

             // get a map containing the attributes of this node
                 NamedNodeMap attributes = element.getAttributes();

             // get the number of nodes in this map

             int numAttrs = attributes.getLength();


             for (int i = 0; i < numAttrs; i++) {
            Attr attr = (Attr) attributes.item(i);
            String attrName = attr.getNodeName();

 String attrValue = attr.getNodeValue();
  System.out.println("Found attribute: " + attrName + " with value: " + attrValue);

             }
 }
```

call this method by using following call in the main method

```
  NodeList entries = doc.getElementsByTagName("NameOfTheNode");
                int num = entries.getLength();
                 for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
                                                  Element node = (Element) entries.item(i);
                                                  listAllAttributes(node);

                          }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NodeList bList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("base");
Node node1 = bList.item(0);

if (node1.getNodeType() == node1.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                     Element ele = (Element) node1;
                     System.out.print("Attribute : ");
                     System.out.println(ele.getAttributes());
                  }
```

Should work.

Very nice explanation is given at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_xml_quick_guide.htm You can refer that for more clarity.